# Database Function

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, oracle

I want to program a C# Function to handle all database calls which return a `list<>`. Now since I want this function to handle multiple List Types, I have to be able to pass any List Type in the function (e.g `List<Student>`, `List<Teacher>`). I just found out one solution approach which is not quite the way i'd liked since i cannot return a value with my approach:

```
    private void Execute<T>(string strSql, List<T> list)
    {
        using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cnnStr))
        {
            using (OracleCommand objCommand = new OracleCommand(strSql, conn))
            {
                objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(objCommand);
                conn.Open();
                adp.Fill(dt);
                if (dt != null)
                {
                    GetListType(list)
                    list = ConvertToList(dt).ToList();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Since my parameter is a `List<T>` it is not possible to return a value since the function then has to be a void.

Any Suggestion how I could pass any list in the function and also be able to return the list?

Many Thanks in advance

Comment: What makes you think you need to return void? You can still return `List<T>`. It's also not clear why you're passing this list *into* the function in the first place.

Comment: Why is your parameter a `List<T>`? If you want to *assign* something to the variable that *references* that list (which was instantiated somewhere outside the method), you might want to give the parameter with the `ref` keyword (i.e. `private void Execute<T>(string strSql, ref List<T> list)`). -- or simply **return** a list, i.e. `private List<T> Execute<T>(string strSql) { var list = new List<T>(); [...] return list; }`. ... or maybe you want to `Add` everything returned by `ConvertToList(dt)` in a loop to that list...

Comment: check out dapper. You can use that quite easily to get an `IEnumerable<T>`, which can then be either converted or inserted (using `AddRange`) to a `List<T>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a reference parameter. It will pass your list by reference and will allow it to be changed in the calling routine.

```
private void Execute<T>(string strSql, ref List<T> list)
{
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cnnStr))
    {
        using (OracleCommand objCommand = new OracleCommand(strSql, conn))
        {
            objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(objCommand);
            conn.Open();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            if (dt != null)
            {
                GetListType(list)
                list = ConvertToList(dt).ToList();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Or use an out parameter, which will need to be declared in the calling routine first

```
private void Execute<T>(string strSql, List<T> list, out List<T> returnList)
{
    using (OracleConnection conn = new OracleConnection(cnnStr))
    {
        using (OracleCommand objCommand = new OracleCommand(strSql, conn))
        {
            objCommand.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            OracleDataAdapter adp = new OracleDataAdapter(objCommand);
            conn.Open();
            adp.Fill(dt);
            if (dt != null)
            {
                GetListType(list)
                list = ConvertToList(dt).ToList();
            }
        }
    }

    returnList = list;

}
```